# how to make a request?

Tags: sql

I have a table Tabl1 : id, name, country, year, medal.
how can I find the top 10 countries by the number of medals for each year in 1 request?

thanks:)

Comment: What have you tried? Have you researched how to aggregate and group?

Comment: and what's your DBMS and its version ??

Comment: Oh sure, what i can do: find the top 10 countries by medal count and medal count for each year. But I can't all together

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18369.0

Answer (score 0):

here you can get the top 10  countries in each year:

```
select * from 
(
  select country,year,count(*),row_number() over (order by count(*) desc) as rn
  from table
  group by country, year
) tt
where tt.rn < 11
```

the sub query groups the data per country and year and gives you count() of each group, but at the same time It sorts them per count(*) desc and gives the a row number per each group ( it happanes using row_number() window funcion) , so the country with the most medal in eacg year is on top and it gets row number = 1 in each group , you need top 10 , so you filter them tt.rn < 11 in the main query.

Comment: thanks :) this solution is clear to me. But I don’t understand why it doesn’t work.

Comment: Do you want 10 per year or 10 total?

Comment: @Viki , that's why you need to provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us anything about your table schema or the data, so this is a guess!

Going to assume your `medal` column contains the qty of medals for each Id/name, so you just need to `rank` by the `sum` of medals. Something along the lines of:

```
select [year], country, [Rank] from (
    select [year], country, Rank() over(partition by [year] order by Sum(medal) desc ) [Rank]
    from Tabl1
    group by [year],country
)x
where [Rank]<=10
order by [year], [Rank]
```

Comment: wow, thanks :) But the medals are NVARCHAR (100). I look at your decision and understand that I still have a lot to learn :(

Comment: Ok, in which case you can replace `sum` with `count`

Answer (score 0):

If you want 10 countries *per year*:

```
with data as (
    select country, "year" as yr,
        rank() over (partition by "year" order by count(*) desc) as rnk
    from T
    group by country, "year"
)
select yr as "year", country from data
where rnk <= 10
order by yr, rnk;
```

Note that if ties are possible this could return more than ten rows for any given year.